# probability in increasing order

Tags: probability

question:
If we have numbers 1 to 100 and then we choose 20 numbers without putting them back in the set then whats the probability of "the 20 numbers being in increasing order" ?
 thanks everybody

Answer (score 2):

There is only way that a permutation of $n$ numbers is increasing. You can choose 20 numbers in $100 \choose 20$ ways. Can you come up with an answer using this information? Let me know if you need one more hint.

Comment: It doesn't matter which numbers are selected.  For *any* $20$ numbers so chosen, there are $20!$ ways these numbers could be drawn; but only one such is in increasing order.